# challenging inequality with complex numbers

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

**The statement of the problem:** Let $n \in \mathbb N $ \ {0} and $z_1,z_2, ... z_n \in \mathbb C $. Prove that $$\sum_{i=1}^n |z_i||z-z_i| \ge \sum_{i=1}^n |z_i|^2$$  holds for any $z \in \mathbb C $ $\iff$
$z_1+z_2+...z_n=0$

**My approach** : I tried to prove the inequality using Cauchy's inequality and the modulus inequality, but I reached some ambiguous results, from which it does not appear that their sum would be 0. I think that the solution can also be a geometric one given the condition that z1 +z2+... zn = 0 it turns out that the vertices of the polygon with these affixes is regular, but I'm not sure.

Any and all proofs will be helpful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use `\ge` to get $\ge$ in MathJax

Comment: The inequality holds for $n=1$, $z=0$, and $z_1=1$, while $\sum_{i=1}^nz_1=1\neq0$.

Comment: @JohnBentin: As I understand it, the task is to show that $$
 \left( \forall z \in \Bbb C: \sum_{i=1}^n |z_i||z-z_i| \ge \sum_{i=1}^n |z_i|^2 \right) \iff z_1+z_2+\cdots + z_n=0
$$

Comment: OK, I get it. Put that way, I can't misread it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a proof using Triangle Inequality and Cauchy-Schwarz

**(i.)**  when $\sum_{k=1}^n z_k = 0$
$\sum_{k=1}^n  \vert z_k\vert^2= \Big \vert \sum_{k=1}^n  \overline z_k \cdot z_k - \overline z_k\cdot z\Big\vert = \Big \vert \sum_{k=1}^n \overline z_k (z_k-z)\Big\vert$
$\leq  \sum_{k=1}^n \Big \vert \overline z_k (z_k-z)\Big\vert=\sum_{k=1}^n \Big \vert z_k\Big \vert \cdot \Big \vert z-z_k\Big\vert$
by triangle inequality

**(ii.)** now suppose the inequality remains true when $\sum_{k=1}^n z_k =\lambda\neq 0$, then Cauchy-Schwarz tells us
$\sum_{k=1}^n  \vert z_k\vert^2\leq \sum_{k=1}^n \Big \vert z_k\Big \vert \cdot \Big \vert z-z_k\Big\vert\leq 
\Big(\sum_{k=1}^n \vert z_k\vert^2\Big)^\frac{1}{2} \cdot \Big(\sum_{k=1}^n \Big \vert z-z_k\Big\vert^2\Big)^\frac{1}{2}$
$\implies\sum_{k=1}^n  \vert z_k\vert^2\leq \sum_{k=1}^n \Big(z -\overline z_k\big)\overline{\Big(z - \overline z_k\Big)}=  n \vert z\vert^2 + \Big(\sum_{k=1}^n   \vert z_k\vert^2\Big)-   2\cdot \text{Re}\Big(z \sum_{k=1}^n z_k\Big)$
$\implies  2\cdot \text{Re}\Big(z\cdot \lambda\Big)\leq  n \vert z\vert^2 $
which is obviously false, e.g. set $z:=\frac{\overline \lambda}{2n}$

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: @LastX I think the last part of the derivation is in error so that the last line should be $2\Re(\bar z\lambda)\le n|z|^2$. This has however no impact on the conclusion.

Comment: Since the inequality holds for all $z \in \mathbb C$ then $\sum_{k=1}^n  \vert z_k\vert^2\leq 
\sum_{k=1}^n \Big \vert z-z_k\Big\vert^2\iff \sum_{k=1}^n  \vert z_k\vert^2\leq \sum_{k=1}^n \Big \vert \overline z- z_k\Big\vert^2\iff \sum_{k=1}^n  \vert z_k\vert^2\leq \sum_{k=1}^n \Big \vert z-\overline z_k\Big\vert^2$ so there is nothing inacurate in what I wrote. Sometimes the scaffolding used to get to the solution persists into the answer I post.

Answer (score 3):

For convenience, we will use engineering notation $z^*$ for the complex conjugate of $z$ and statistical notation $\bar z$ for the arithmetic mean of the $z_i\;$ ($i=1,...,n$).

First, let us assume $$\sum_{i=1}^n |z_i||z-z_i|\geqslant \sum_{i=1}^n|z_i|^2 \quad\text{for all}\;z\in\Bbb C.\qquad(1)$$
We have
$$\begin{align}0&\leqslant\sum_{i=1}^n(|z_i|-|z-z_i|)^2\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n(|z_i|^2-2|z-z_i||z_i|+|z-z_i|^2)\\
&\leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n(|z_i|^2-2|z_i|^2+|z-z_i|^2)\quad\text{(by ineq. 1)}\qquad(*)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n(|z-z_i|^2-|z_i|^2)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n[(z-z_i)(z^*-z_i^*)-z_iz_i^*]\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n(zz^*-z_iz^*-zz_i^*)\\
&=n(x^2+y^2)-2x\sum_{i=1}^nx_i-2y\sum_{i=1}^ny_i\quad\text{(where $z=x+\mathrm iy$ with $x,y\in\Bbb R$, etc.)}\\
&=n[(x-\bar x)^2+(y-\bar y)^2-\bar x^2-\bar y^2].\qquad(**)
\end{align}$$
Overall, we may conclude that $0\leqslant (x-\bar x)^2+(y-\bar y)^2-\bar x^2-\bar y^2$ for all real $x$ and $y$. In particular, this is the case  when $x=\frac12\bar x$ and $y=\frac12\bar y\,$: namely, $0\leqslant-\frac34(\bar x^2+\bar y^2)$. It follows that $\bar x=\bar y=0$.

To prove the converse implication, we will obtain a contradiction by assuming, contrary to inequality $1$, that there is $z_0=x_0+\mathrm iy_0$, with $x_0,y_0\in \Bbb R$, such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n|z_i||z_0-z_i|<\sum_{i=1}^n|z_i|^2\qquad(2)$$
while also $\sum_{i=1}^nz_i=0$. We use the same algebraic manipulations as above, but work backwards from line $**$ with $\bar x=\bar y=0$, replacing $z$ by $z_0$, and replacing $\leqslant$ by $>$ (from the contrary inequality $2)$ in line $*$. Consequently, we get

$$\sum_{i=1}^n(|z_i|-|z_0-z_i|)^2>\sum_{i=1}^n|z_0|^2.$$
Now write this as $\sum_{i=1}^n[(|z_i|-|z_0-z_i|)^2-|z_0|^2]>0$ and factorize to get
$$\sum_{i=1}^n(|z_i|-|z_0-z_i|-|z_0|)(||z_i|-|z_0-z_i|+|z_0|)>0.$$
However, by the triangle inequality, the first factor of each term of the above sum is non-positive while the second factor is non-negative. So the sum is non-positive: the required contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the derivative mechanism with $z$ and $z^*$ (the complex conjugate) treated as independent variables. But if you aren't familiar with it, first study it to convince yourself that this is a consistent procedure for functions that are analytical in $z$ and in $z^*$, otherwise it would be black magic... We first define, for convenience:
$$
 X = \sum_{i=1}^n|z_i|\ |z-z_i| - \sum_{i=1}^n|z_i|^2 \geq 0
$$
We observe that we have $X=0$ in the origin ($z=0$).
We now need to make the expression for $X$ analytical in $z$ and in $z^*$, like this:
$$
 X = \sum_{i=1}^n\left(|z_i|\ \sqrt{(z-z_i)(z^*-z_i^*)} - |z_i|^2\right)  \geq 0
$$
Note that we do not care about the $z_i$, they can remain in the non-analytical |z_i|, we are only going to differentiate w.r.t. $z$ and $z^*$, giving:
$$
 \frac{dX}{dz^*} =    \frac{d}{dz^*}
 \sum_{i=1}^n|z_i|\sqrt{(z-z_i)(z^*-z_i^*)} =
 \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{|z_i|\ (z-z_i)/2}{\sqrt{(z-z_i)(z^*-z_i^*)}}
$$
$$  \mbox{ and similarly} \ \ \ \ 
 \frac{dX}{dz} = 
 \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{|z_i|\ (z^*-z_i^*)/2}{\sqrt{(z-z_i)(z^*-z_i^*)}},
$$
and then we look at the result in the origin where $z=z^*=0$, giving:
$$
 \left. \frac{dX}{dz^*}\right|_{z=0} =  
 \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{|z_i|\ (-z_i)/2}{\sqrt{z_i  z_i^*}} =
 -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n\ z_i, \ \ \ \
\mbox{and} \ \ \ \
 \left. \frac{dX}{dz}\right|_{z=0} =  
 -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n\ z_i^*
$$
Now the finishing touch: because $X=0$ in the origin and has to be non-negative in any region around the origin it *cannot* have a finite first-order derivative! This means that the $\sum_{i=1}^n\ z_i$ that we encountered in the derivatives must be zero, $\frac{1}{2}$QED.

NB: without the originally given restriction, the expansion of $X$ around the origin would have been:
$$
 X = c + \alpha z + \alpha^* z^* + \beta z^2 + \beta^* (z^*)^2
 + \gamma z z^* + \mbox{higher orders},
$$
but in this case we saw that $c=0$ and our given inequality then requires the first derivatives to be zero: $\alpha=\alpha^*=0$. With some further reasoning you can even find that $\beta$ should be $0$. We still might have $\gamma\neq 0$ (it should then be positive!)

Comment: I haven't learned about derivatives yet, but thanks for the help! Do you know of any other solution to this problem that does not include derivatives ?

Comment: Not immediately... (but instead of those complex $z$ and $z^*$ derivatives you could rewrite the whole problem in terms of real 2-vectors with dot products and then use derivatives wrt. the real vector components).

Comment: what means z* ?

Comment: Complex conjugate! (And for the derivative wrt. $z^*$, if you want to study it look on the web, e.g. here: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/partial-derivative-with-respect-to-complex-conjugate.461859/  If you want to go to 2-vectors instead, the derivative will just be wrt. the x and y-components so then it doesn't matter. But it is clumsy to first have to translate to vectors and then doing every derivative for two variables instead of one.)

Comment: thank you for your time !

Comment: Why did you replace the inequality with equality?

Comment: Sorry for my first sloppy description! I just wanted to present the methodology (not even knowing whether it would be useful... but it actually is a nice example problem  so I now expanded my description a bit! See new edited version).

Comment: Now it looks nice. But does not this prove only $\implies$ part of the statement?

Comment: I overlooked that completely! (Since I started by just suggesting the approach and leaving the details for others, and then I decided to add some more details but didn't look at the question again :) I now changed the QED... )